# Change ::selection based on data-theme

Tags: css

Is it possible to change the selection style with `::selection` based on `data-theme`'s value?

For example, this works:

```css
::selection {
  color: green;
  background: yellow;
}
```

But none of these work:

```css
[data-theme="dark"] ::selection {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

[data-theme="light"] ::selection {
  color: green;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, you need to remove space   between `[data-theme="light"]` and `::selection`.

Correct way is `[data-theme="light"]::selection`

```css
[data-theme="dark"]::selection {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

[data-theme="light"]::selection {
  color: green;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p data-theme="dark">Hello World</p>
<p data-theme="light">Hello World</p>
```